# Asignar valor a variable con resultado de sp - SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo un procedimiento almacenado que da como resultado un varchar, y este trato de asignarlo a una variable en otro SP, pero me da un error.

```
DECLARE @SERVER VARCHAR (50);
SET @SERVER = (EXEC SP_OBTIENE_SERVER_UIP73);
```

ERROR
Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de la palabra clave 'EXEC'.

Version SQL 2008

Comment: Un SP solamente retorna enteros, a menos que sea un parámetro de salida. ¿cuál es la declaración de `SP_OBTIENE_SERVER_UIP3`?

Answer (score 0):

Una solución simple, es asignar el resultado del sp a un conjunto, y de este extraer la única row que tiene que devolver.

```
Create procedure SP_OBTIENE_SERVER_UIP73 
As
Begin

Select 'cadena devuelta';

End
GO
```

Si intentas recuperar el valor en una variable, este te genera una salida incorrecta.

```
DECLARE @SERVER VARCHAR(50);
EXEC @SERVER = SP_OBTIENE_SERVER_UIP73;
SELECT @SERVER
GO
```

[image: Resultado]

Pero es fácilmente adaptable, capturar la salida del sp en un conjunto (variable tipo tabla).

```
DECLARE @SERVER VARCHAR(50); -- la variable que necesitas
DECLARE @SERVERTABLE TABLE (CADENA VARCHAR(50)); -- el conjunto de trabajo

INSERT INTO @SERVERTABLE
EXEC SP_OBTIENE_SERVER_UIP73; -- lo que retorna el sp, lo metemos en el conjunto

SELECT TOP(1)@SERVER= CADENA FROM @SERVERTABLE; -- asignamos la primera fila a la variable

SELECT @SERVER; -- resultado
```

[image: Resultado Final]